# Can this oracle query be tuned anymore?

Tags: sql, performance, oracle10g

I'm trying to minimize the cost of this query as much as possible without creating any indexes.

This is the original query with a cost of 599:

```
SELECT DISTINCT OL.PRODUCT_ID
FROM ORDERS O JOIN ORDER_LINES OL ON (O.ORDER_ID = OL.ORDER_ID)
              JOIN PRODUCTS P     ON (OL.PRODUCT_ID = P.PRODUCT_ID)
              JOIN CUSTOMERS C    ON (C.CUSTOMER_ID = O.CUSTOMER_ID)
WHERE C.CUSTOMER_ID = 474871
      OR UPPER(C.FIRST_NAME) = 'EDGAR';
```

This is what I've done so far. The cost is now 344:

```
SELECT OL.PRODUCT_ID
FROM ORDER_LINES OL
WHERE EXISTS
  (SELECT ORDER_ID 
   FROM ORDERS
   WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = 474871
         AND ORDER_ID = OL.ORDER_ID)
OR EXISTS
  (SELECT ORDER_ID
   FROM ORDERS
   WHERE CUSTOMER_ID IN 
     (SELECT CUSTOMER_ID 
      FROM CUSTOMERS 
      WHERE UPPER(FIRST_NAME) = 'EDGAR')
  AND ORDER_ID = OL.ORDER_ID);
```

Is there anything that stands out that I may try to drive down the cost more?
Here is a screen shot of the explain plan: [image: Explain Plan]

Screenshot of ERD: [image: ERD]

Comment: instead of using ORDERS table as first, use CUSTOMERS tabel because you are using where clause on it..

Comment: Cost is a poor method to use to measure performance. Cost is there to evaluate a plan against other plans for the same query. Comparing costs between different queries tends to be more misleading than helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the cost is misleading and may lead you to make changes that aren't actually beneficial. To quote [Tom Kyte](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:313416745628), "You cannot compare the cost of 2 queries with each other. ... they might as well be random numbers."

The best way to check query performance is to actually time the query, ideally with realistic data. You should also be wary of premature optimization. Your first query is pretty straight-forward; I would stick with it unless a performance issue manifests.

Comment: + 1 Premature optimization

Comment: I'm glad you pointed this out, but for the purposes of my sql tuning class. The instructor only cares about cost. I'm not sure why. So far my query has the best cost. I only posted here so I could nickel and dime it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm curious if the engine is smart enough to apply the where clause before the joins... If it's doing it after the join, then the results it has to scan are larger than they need to be... What happens if you move the limiting criteria to the join so it HAS to be evaluated before the join occurs.  (fully expect this to be 599 or less.  just don't know if it will be less...

```
SELECT OL.PRODUCT_ID
FROM CUSTOMERS C 
INNER JOIN ORDERS O       
  ON (C.CUSTOMER_ID = O.CUSTOMER_ID)
 AND (C.customer_ID = 47871 OR upper(C.First_name) = 'EDGAR')
INNER JOIN ORDER_LINES OL ON (O.ORDER_ID = OL.ORDER_ID)
INNER JOIN PRODUCTS P     ON (OL.PRODUCT_ID = P.PRODUCT_ID)
GROUP BY OL.Product_ID
```

I wonder if the OR is causing the problem....

if you run it w/o the or how much cost is reduced

and then what happens if you union the two sets instead of using an or.

```
SELECT OL.PRODUCT_ID
FROM CUSTOMERS C 
INNER JOIN ORDERS O       
  ON (C.CUSTOMER_ID = O.CUSTOMER_ID)
INNER JOIN ORDER_LINES OL ON (O.ORDER_ID = OL.ORDER_ID)
INNER JOIN PRODUCTS P     ON (OL.PRODUCT_ID = P.PRODUCT_ID)
WHERE  C.customer_ID = 47871 
UNION
SELECT OL.PRODUCT_ID
FROM CUSTOMERS C 
INNER JOIN ORDERS O       
  ON (C.CUSTOMER_ID = O.CUSTOMER_ID)
INNER JOIN ORDER_LINES OL ON (O.ORDER_ID = OL.ORDER_ID)
INNER JOIN PRODUCTS P     ON (OL.PRODUCT_ID = P.PRODUCT_ID)
WHERE upper(C.First_name) = 'EDGAR')
```

Comment: Seems odd that the full table scan on ordered_Items is occurring. there a **Working** index or at least a PK/FK relationship on order_ID?

Comment: ORDER_LINES PK ORDER_ID AND PK, FK1 PRODUCT_ID

Comment: Then why isn't the engine using the index... it's doing a full table scan...odd...

Comment: @xQbert: if the query is likely to return a large enough portion of `ORDER_LINES`, then the optimizer may (correctly) choose to do a full-table scan over using the index.

Comment: @Allan I get that, the assumption I'm making is that the majority of the order_lines are NOT being returned here. 1 customer code or first name edgar... seems odd that would be the "BULK" of the order lines...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT OL.PRODUCT_ID
FROM ORDER_LINES OL
WHERE OL.ORDER_ID IN 
        (SELECT ORDER_ID FROM ORDERS
         WHERE CUSTOMER_ID IN (SELECT CUSTOMER_ID FROM CUSTOMERS 
                               WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = 474871 OR UPPER(FIRST_NAME) = 'EDGAR')
        );
```

I suppose there is an index on `OL.ORDER_ID` (now you have FULL SCAN of ORDER_LINES)

Comment: It is the primary key.

Comment: The cost for this query is 558.

Comment: @billabrian6 I suppose that the customer which orders you're looking for makes a lot of orders or something wrong with the statistics. Are you sure that ORDER_ID in ORDER_LINES is a primary key?